# iPhone family sharing: removed family member can't change country in account

Tags: iphone

I wanted to download the netflix app on my gf's phone, and in order to do that I have to change her country, because the netflix app is not available in my country.

Problem is, when I tried doing that, it said that only the owner of the family (she's added to my family sharing) can change the country. I removed her from family sharing temporarily but it still says that only the owner of the family can change the country setting.

What's the problem here, how do I resolve this?

Comment: If her device says she's not in a family but still shows that message, you need to contact Apple Support to figure out what's wrong

Comment: It worked eventually, I guess you gotta wait a bit longer